# Sphinx different background images for different pages

Tags: python, html, css, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I am working on a Sphinx website and I have the index.html as the base layout. It has a background image that I defined on body in my css file. I have the navbar links like about, projects etc. I want to use a background color on these instead of a background image how can I achieve that ? I tried this on the RST file :

```
.. raw:: html

<embed>
   <style>
      body {
      background-color:white !important;
      }
   </style>
</embed>
```

but this code does not work. Is there any way to make it happen ?

Comment: What do you mean "it does not work"?  What do you observe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you see the background image that you set elsewhere instead of the background color ("it does not work"), you must override that `background-image: url('foo.png');` CSS property as well.

```
.. raw:: html

<embed>
   <style>
      body {
        background-color: white;
        background-image: none !important;
      }
   </style>
</embed>
```

I think this is an ugly way to go about it, though.

I would prefer to use Jinja2 templates and an external style sheet. In other words, modify your Jinja2 template to insert an `id="{{ pagename }}"` into the `<body>` tag. The value of `id` must be unique across all your pages. Then in my custom style sheet, add appropriate selectors:

```
body#index {
    background-color: white;
}

body#subpage {
    background-image: url('moosehair.png');
}
```